# how to call DataStage job from an API

Tags: api, datastage

I have a requirement to call /run a DataStage job from an API.
Please provide reference links/websites/steps

API-->DS job

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about this question because it's all documented online. But since I am not the kind of person who likes to admonish how to search the internet, I will give you some entry points.

### Running a job from the command line

This is a short explanation or let's say the fast lane:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=jobs-running-job-from-command-line

### Commands for controlling InfoSphere DataStage jobs

Probably the standard practice.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=interface-commands-controlling-infosphere-datastage-jobs

### Using the DataStage FlowDesigner API

This is the API which is also used by the DataFlow Designer. Since I've never tested it, I can't recommend it, but also can't advise against it either. It exists.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=designer-rest-api

### InfoSphere DataStage Development Kit (Job Control Interfaces)

If you want to go more in-depth to include job controls in your own application, this reference is for you.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=reference-infosphere-datastage-development-kit-job-control-interfaces